# How to debug a script by removing the "if"?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I have the following code:

```
debug=$?
function a {
    su - javi -c "uptime"
    return $debug
}

function b {
    su - javi -c "cat /etc/redhat-release"
    return $debug
}

function c {
    su - javi -c "cat /etc/redhat-release"
    return $debug
}

case $debug in
0)
    a
    if [ $debug == 0 ]; then
        b
        echo "se ejcuta la funcion"
    elif [ $debug == 0 ]
        c   
    elif[].... <-----this

    fi
;;

1)
    echo "se ha producido un error"
;;

esac
```

Is there any way to debug by removing the if ??I want them to go running a function if it ends well that jumps to the other function and if it does not end well that it leaves the escript, that with 5 functions

Comment: `ìf false ; then`followed by `# if`?

Comment: You also don't need the `su` operation to run `uptime` or to read `/etc/redhat-release`. And why do you `return $debug` from your functions when it's a global variable, and you ignore the return value anyway?

Comment: To do what you want, you need to reset $debug with the result of the previous command.  Since you're not doing that it looks like all your tests are measuring the initial value of $debug, which incidentally, is `$?`... not sure what that would be in a new subshell.  is it just the value of the last command run?

Comment: @Tim yes it is. So here Ortiga could run `false; ./myscript.sh` to enable debug or `true; ./myscript.sh` to keep it off. But it would also get triggered with two commands such as `ls /does/not/exist` then `./myscript.sh`

Comment: Ortiga, you probably want to run this through https://shellcheck.net/ You're missing space around the `[` and `]` characters, for starters. And `==` is a string comparison. Use `-eq` for a numeric one.

Comment: having the `if` and `elif` test the same variable for the same value probably isn't helping either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is simply to run each function, and bail out of there was any errors, maybe something like this will work:

```
function bail {
    echo "se ha producido un error ($1)"
    exit 1
}

function a {
    uptime
}

function b {
    cat /etc/redhat-release
}

function c { 
    cat /etc/redhat-release
}

for f in 'a' 'b' 'c'; do
    $f || bail "$f: $?"
done
```

This will run each function, and if an error is encountered, the function name and exit code are sent to the `bail` function, which will print a line and bail out of any additional commands.

I did remove the use of `su` because it was easier to test that way. If you want to automate this, I'd recommend creating a sudo profile to run those commands with elevated privileges in such a way that you only need to enter your password once, or no times at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. `debug=$?` is not evaluated at every command. So the value of `debug` will be the same throughout the entire script.
2. The return code of a function is the return code of its last command. So the return statements are pointless.

In summary, something like `a && b && c` will run `b` if `a` succeeds, and will run `c` if `b` succeeds. The return code of this compound command is the first non-zero return code of each of the functions.